# displaying text from select option with added element in the result

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Guys i need a little help about this code here. So i want to display the option like this : "Fried Rice = 10.000" as the result, but in this code the text from select option box also have the price. For the final result i need the text from select option only have the text (without price), while after i press order button it will display text from select option name + " = " + price. Any idea what should i change?

```js
var data = {
  Food: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Fried Rice',
      price: '10.000'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Fried Noodle',
      price: '9.000'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Pancake',
      price: '8.500'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'French Fries',
      price: '7.500'
    }
  ],
  Drink: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Cola',
      price: '4.600'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Orange Juice',
      price: '5.400'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Mineral Water',
      price: '3.500'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Coffee',
      price: '5.800'
    }
  ]
}

function handleChange() {
  var x = document.getElementById("category_select").value;

  var dataOptions = data[x]
  var dataSelect = document.getElementById('type_select')
  dataSelect.innerHTML = ''

  dataOptions.forEach(function(option) {
    var optionEle = document.createElement('option')
    optionEle.value = option.id
    optionEle.label = option.name + " = " + option.price

    dataSelect.appendChild(optionEle)
  })

}
handleChange()

$(document).ready(function() {
  var selectMenu = [];
  $("button").click(function() {
    selectMenu.push($("#type_select option:selected").attr('label'));
    $(".result").html(selectMenu.join('<br>'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <h2 style="font-size:70px; font-family:Lucida Console;">MENU</h2>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" id="category_select" onChange='handleChange()'>
          <option value="Food">Food</option>
          <option value="Drink">Drink</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" id="type_select"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Order</button>
<br>
<br>
<div class="result text-center"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `attribute` inside your option tag with name `data-price` this will have price value and then show same .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var data = {
  Food: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Fried Rice',
      price: '10.000'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Fried Noodle',
      price: '9.000'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Pancake',
      price: '8.500'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'French Fries',
      price: '7.500'
    }
  ],
  Drink: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Cola',
      price: '4.600'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Orange Juice',
      price: '5.400'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Mineral Water',
      price: '3.500'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Coffee',
      price: '5.800'
    }
  ]
}

function handleChange() {
  var x = document.getElementById("category_select").value;

  var dataOptions = data[x]
  var dataSelect = document.getElementById('type_select')
  dataSelect.innerHTML = ''

  dataOptions.forEach(function(option) {
    var optionEle = document.createElement('option')
    optionEle.value = option.id
    optionEle.setAttribute('data-price', option.price)//atr with price
    optionEle.label = option.name

    dataSelect.appendChild(optionEle)
  })

}
handleChange()

$(document).ready(function() {
  var selectMenu = [];
  $("button").click(function() {
  //get price and name from selected options
    selectMenu.push($("#type_select option:selected").attr('label') +" = "+$("#type_select option:selected").data('price'));
    $(".result").html(selectMenu.join('<br>'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <h2 style="font-size:70px; font-family:Lucida Console;">MENU</h2>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" id="category_select" onChange='handleChange()'>
          <option value="Food">Food</option>
          <option value="Drink">Drink</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" id="type_select"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Order</button>
<br>
<br>
<div class="result text-center"></div>
```